# Proving $M$ is $k$-manifold without boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I've been proving the following theorem from "Analysis on Manifold" by Munkres:

**Theorem**: Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+k} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be of class $C^{r}$. Let $M$ be the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Assume that $M$ is non-empty and that $Df(x)$ has rank $k$ for $x \in M$. Then $M$ is a $k$-manifold without boundary in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.

I don't see how we can obtain patch coordinate on $M$ about $p \in M$.

Any helps would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the case where $n = k = 1$.  Now use the implicit function theorem.